# Form designer app with mysql data submission

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I want to develop an app in PHP with following features

- User can create multiple form using a form designer with as many field they wanted
- Every form submission will be stored in mysql
- User can see respective form submission later

I have done the UI part and form designer.

**Problem**

I am not able to figure out how to design database for accepting form submission, for instance If an user created a form with following fields

- Name
- Email
- City
- Subject
- Query

But later user can add or remove fields without messing with the database design.

**Please help me with MySQL database design for storing form into table and there submission.**

Comment: Another case of taking something that is best suited to NoSQL and stuffing it into MySQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE forms (
  form_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, -- the UID of this form
  owner   INT,                                     -- the user who "owns" the form
  PRIMARY KEY (form_id)
);

CREATE TABLE fields (
  form_id  BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  field    VARCHAR(10),                            -- the field name
  PRIMARY KEY (form_id, field),
  FOREIGN KEY (form_id) REFERENCES forms (form_id)
);

CREATE TABLE submissions (
  submission_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  form_id       BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  field         VARCHAR(10),
  value         BLOB,                              -- stores PHP's serialize($var)
  PRIMARY KEY (submission_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (form_id) REFERENCES forms (form_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (form_id, field) REFERENCES fields (form_id, field)
);
```

I would suggest that modifications to a form's design create a new (copy) form in the database, so as not to invalidate any historical submissions based on the old design.